# What does "looking at the world without time" mean?

Tags: meaning

In *The Matrix Reloaded* (2003), Oracle says to Neo:

> Oracle: You have the sight now, Neo. You are **looking at the world
> without time**.

What does "looking at the world without time" mean?

Comment: This is not an English question.

Comment: @Lambie How not? It's obviously a question about English, so what are you actually objecting to that would be helpful to the OP?

Comment: @gotube The English portion of the question is simply that it is written in English.  The plain meaning can be answered with a dictionary.  The concept is a complicated idea however, and what the asker seems to really be asking is more regarding science or philosophy, which is out of scope for ELL.

Comment: @RichardWinters I read the question as asking if there's an idiomatic meaning to the phrase, which it turns out there isn't. James K's answer addresses it from this perspective and got the checkmark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is completely literal.

Neo is able to perceive the whole of reality, not just the present but also the past and future. As such he can see the world without time.

This is because it is a science fiction movie and so things that aren't real can be real in the movie.

Comment: If you can see the whole of reality, you can sure see "all time".